# Problems working with async Task and Textbox.Text = "Hello"

Tags: c#, async-await, google-cloud-speech

First of all, sorry because I am so new at C# and I decided to make this question because I have been choked in this for hours.

I have an GUI that works with Google Cloud Speech services and make a Speech-to-Text operation. I share with you the whole method that runs when a button is clicked:

```
private async Task<object> StreamingMicRecognizeAsync(int seconds)
    {
        if (NAudio.Wave.WaveIn.DeviceCount < 1)
        {
            Console.WriteLine("No microphone!");
            return -1;
        }

        GoogleCredential googleCredential;
        using (Stream m = new FileStream(@"..\..\credentials.json", FileMode.Open))
            googleCredential = GoogleCredential.FromStream(m);
        var channel = new Grpc.Core.Channel(SpeechClient.DefaultEndpoint.Host,
            googleCredential.ToChannelCredentials());
        var speech = SpeechClient.Create(channel);

        var streamingCall = speech.StreamingRecognize();

        // Write the initial request with the config.
        await streamingCall.WriteAsync(
            new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
            {
                StreamingConfig = new StreamingRecognitionConfig()
                {
                    Config = new RecognitionConfig()
                    {
                        Encoding =
                        RecognitionConfig.Types.AudioEncoding.Linear16,
                        SampleRateHertz = 48000,
                        LanguageCode = "es-ES",
                    },
                    InterimResults = true,
                }
            });

        // Read from the microphone and stream to API.
        object writeLock = new object();
        bool writeMore = true;
        var waveIn = new NAudio.Wave.WaveInEvent();
        waveIn.DeviceNumber = 0;
        waveIn.WaveFormat = new NAudio.Wave.WaveFormat(48000, 1);
        waveIn.DataAvailable +=
            (object sender, NAudio.Wave.WaveInEventArgs args) =>
            {
                lock (writeLock)
                {
                    if (!writeMore) return;
                    streamingCall.WriteAsync(
                        new StreamingRecognizeRequest()
                        {
                            AudioContent = Google.Protobuf.ByteString
                                .CopyFrom(args.Buffer, 0, args.BytesRecorded)
                        }).Wait();
                }
            };

        // Print responses as they arrive.
        Task printResponses = Task.Run(async () =>
        {
            while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(default(CancellationToken)))
            {
                foreach (var result in streamingCall.ResponseStream
                    .Current.Results)
                {
                    foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                    {
                        Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);
                        //Textbox1.Text = alternative.Transcript;
                    }
                }
            }
        });

        waveIn.StartRecording();
        Console.WriteLine("Speak now.");
        Result_Tone.Text = "Speak now:\n\n";
        await Task.Delay(TimeSpan.FromSeconds(seconds));

        // Stop recording and shut down.
        waveIn.StopRecording();
        lock (writeLock) writeMore = false;
        await streamingCall.WriteCompleteAsync();
        await printResponses;
        return 0;
    }
```

My problem is that I want to update the content of the `Textbox1`control but it doesn´t work. It writes perfectly the output into the console with the line `Console.WriteLine(alternative.Transcript);` but not into my textbox.

If someone could help I would appreciate so much his help.

Comment: Textbox1 was created on the thread where the main method is invoked. This Async method is a separate thread. The exception you are getting is becuase you are trying to update a GUI object from a thread which did not create it. Simple solution, create a Delegate for update and then use Textbox1.Invoke or BeginInvoke

Comment: @mjwills no, it simply breaks my code even my speech-to-text "worker"

Comment: @PrateekShrivastava could you guide me a little?

Comment: General rule of thumb - once you start writing `async`/`await` based code, *any* use of `Task.Run()` (or moral equivalents) should be regarded with suspicion. (it's okay if you need to run other *cpu* heavy work but I'd usually recommend looking for a higher level construct even then that lets you focus on the job at hand)

Answer (score 5):

The problem is that you're using `Task.Run`, which means your code will be running on a thread-pool thread.

Instead of calling `Task.Run()`, just move that code into a separate async method:

```
async Task DisplayResponses(IAsyncEnumerator<StreamingRecognizeResponse> responses)
{
    while (await responses.MoveNext(default(CancellationToken)))
    {
        foreach (var result in responses.Current.Results)
        {
            foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
            {
                Textbox1.Text = alternative.Transcript;
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then call that method *directly* (without `Task.Run`) from code that's already on the UI thread (e.g. an event handler).

The async machinery will make sure that after the `await` expression, you're back on the UI thread (the same *synchronization context*). So the assignment to the `Text` property will occur on the UI thread, and all should be well.

For example:

```
// This would be registered as the event handler for a button
void HandleButtonClick(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
     var stream = client.StreamingRecognize();
     // Send the initial config request
     await stream.WriteAsync(...);

     // Presumably you want to send audio data...
     StartSendingAudioData(stream);

     await DisplayResponses(stream.ResponseStream);
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer, this was pretty difficult to me but it seems to work.

Comment: @FernandodelCastillo-Olivares: If you're new to C#, I'd really advise you to take things steadily and read up on async/await - it's a pretty advanced topic, but you need a fairly good understanding of it to use it effectively, IMO.

Answer (score 3):

Tasks run on seperate threads, so you must `Invoke` an action that will be performed on the control's thread

```
Textbox1.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    Textbox1.Text= "";
}));
```

Edit: For WPF, I believe the equivalent is

```
Textbox1.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action(() =>
{
    Textbox1.Text= "";
}));
```

Comment: While that *would* work, part of the point of async/await is to allow us to avoid all of that. An async method is the better way to go here, IMO.

Comment: This doesn´t work because I can´t call Invoke method in my textbox:

Comment: @FernandodelCastillo-Olivares is this a WinForms text box or something else?

Comment: @p3tch this is a WPF Textbox

Comment: @FernandodelCastillo-Olivares updated for WPF though Daisy's answer is best

Answer (score 0):

have you tried using Dispatcher.InvokeASync()?

```
await Dispatcher.InvokeAsync(() => {while (await streamingCall.ResponseStream.MoveNext(default(CancellationToken)))
        {
            foreach (var result in streamingCall.ResponseStream
                .Current.Results)
            {
                foreach (var alternative in result.Alternatives)
                {                       
                    Textbox1.Text = alternative.Transcript;
                }
            }
        }});
```

Comment: While this works, you shouldn't need to do this if you start the "display results" task from a UI thread in the first place.